# Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad - Numbers become 'password dots'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I've started making a very basic app, just using labels and text fields. My application was working completely fine and then it just started going weird. Whenever you click on a text field it should bring up the number pad for the phone. This works completely fine for the first input but the second input sometimes doesn't bring up the number pad, and when you do enter something and click off it, that text field just becomes 'password dots'. When clicking the button and the calculation is made, the result is also the 'password dots'. However when printing to the console, it recognises the correct output. The situation is the same whether running through the simulator or running through my phone after building it. I've attached some necessary code below.

I would really appreciate some help, I'm very new to iOS development and see no reason for this error to be occurring. Thanks!

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *deviceType;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *iOSVersion;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *num1Val;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *num2Val;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *answerVal;

- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"Add Pressed");

float num1 = [[self.num1Val text] floatValue];
float num2 = [[self.num2Val text] floatValue];

NSLog(@"Number 1: %f Number 2: %f", num1, num2);

float answer = num1 + num2;
NSLog(@"Answer: %f", answer);

NSString *answerText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", answer];
self.answerVal.text = answerText;

}
```

Comment: Are you using any keyboard avoiding libraries?

Comment: I haven't imported any libraries, I'm running default XCode